# Readdressing home network to expand available hosts - FTP failing

Tags: ftp, subnet

Got a new router so it was a good opportunity to do some fiddling to expand the addresses at my disposal.

Router = 172.16.0.1  Mask = 255.255.252.0

FTP Server = 172.16.0.4

IP Camera = 172.16.1.221 and FTP fails.  The FTP server logs no attempts at connection at all.  But if I change it to 172.16.0.221 it works.

I've checked to make sure the masks are correct across the board, so I'm guessing I'm just not "getting it" when it comes to subnetting.  I thought my available address pool in this configuration would be 172.16.0.1 - 172.16.3.254 and hosts in that range would be able to communicate.

It's odd, because I can access the IP camera's UI from a computer addressed as 172.16.0.10 just fine.

Can anyone point out my error?

Answer (score 1):

Your subnetting looks fine, if you really do use a 255.255.252.0 mask, that's sufficient to talk to hosts on 172.16.3.X as well, without needing routing in between.

You say you have checked the subnetting masks across the board, but I think you must have missed something. Maybe on the router port your ftp server is connected to?

If you leave everything as-is when you have the problem, and you just replace the router with a layer 2 switch, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, weird.  While trying to do something else on the FTP server, it told me that network discovery had been turned off.  I turned it back on and, voila.

I know *I* didn't turn it off, but ever since Microsoft pushed the last update, little things have been "odd."  I guess this was just one of them.

Comment: Glad to hear it got solved.